How to stop pull request from running twice (with a twist)
The project I'm working on has a GitHub Actions workflow file that looks like this:
# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "flom_v1_development" branch
  push:
    branches: ["development"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["development"]
    types:
      - closed

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: self-hosted

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          clean: false

    AND SO ON...

As you can see there are 2 events: push & pull request. What I have found so far is that if I put an if before "steps" that checks whether a PR has merged it will stop the double run. But then "pull" doesn't run either!
I've tried solving that like this:
# Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    steps:

    AND SO ON...

but it still runs twice on PR. Any help?

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, do you want to execute the workflow only when PRs are merge on the development branch ?

Arnaud, I want to execute the workflow ONCE when I merge a PR into the development branch. Right now it executes twice, first once and then a few seconds later again.

Ok, I answered, let me know if this helps

Assuming there won't be other push on the development branch other than when a PR is merged, you can just keep the push event.
Merging a PR automatically triggers a push event so adding pull_request will trigger two workflows.
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "flom_v1_development" branch
  push:
    branches: ["development"]

